# C - Is there a way to call a function pointer if it's not null without repeating the function pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Take this code

```
int main() {
     void (*func)(int val) = NULL;

     if (func) { // check if NULL
          func(0); // call it
     }
}
```

Is there a way to call a function pointer `func` without having to write `func` twice?

Something like

```
func? (0);
```

Comment: Instead of assigning `func` to `NULL`, assigned it to a do nothing function.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a macro:

```
#define CALL_FUNC(func, param) \
  do {                         \
    if (func) func(param);     \
  } while (0)
```

And use it:

```
int main() {
     void (*func)(int val) = NULL;
     CALL_FUNC(func, 0);
}
```

EDIT: I would not recommend it, I used that for some time in my projects. I actually dropped it after some time, it added a little bit a useless complexity.

I finally came back to your current code, but formatted in 1 line:

```
int main() {
     void (*func)(int val) = NULL;

     if (func) func(0);
}
```